# Can BME280 sensor's output be converted to 1-wire protocol?

Tags: 1-wire

Teltonika FMB125 is an advanced GPS Tracking device with a 1-Wire interface to monitor temperature data. I tested a waterproofed version of the DS18B20 temperature sensor with Teltonika FMB125 and I got the temperature reading successfully.

As I am using the sensor to read the temperature of a freezer vehicle which keeps the temperature at -35 ~ -25 °C, the performance of the DS18B20 temperature sensor is not satisfactory. I want to connect a BME280 temperature sensor to the Teltonika FMB125, but the BME280 doesn't come with 1-wire support. Is there any way to convert the BME280 sensor's output to 1-wire protocol so that it can be used with the Teltonika FMB125?

Comment: First make sure your alleged DS18B20 isn't actually a counterfeit fake, ie, get one from a reputable electronics industry distributor or prototype supplier to try; sensors from random e-commerce sites selling to hobbyists which claim to be this device are typically not genuine.

Comment: The BME280 supports both SPI and I2C. Is there a reason why you can't or don't want to use one of those interfaces? Converting bus protocols typically is not trivial and also both I2C and SPI are much faster and (from my experience) more stable than 1-wire.

Comment: The thing is that you don't need generic one-wire, you need something that responds *exactly* like the DS18B20 that your host expects.  And pretty much the _only_ way you're going to get a BME280 to do that is to build a custom bridge with an MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Generic one-wire isn't going to work for you, you need something that **responds exactly like the expected DS18B20** and needs no more setup or initialization than that does.

As such, this would only be possible by inserting an MCU in between which has been programmed and wired to query the readings from the BME280 via I2C or SPI and then encode those as if they had come from a *simulated* 1-wire device when queried by the consuming tracking device.  It's not only the bus protocol which needs to be translated, the sensor has to be configured and operated, and the *meaning* of the information has to be re-interpreted.

More typically, a tracking device made to use this sensor would be engineered to operate it directly over I2C or SPI.

If you want to make this adaption, you'll have to make a custom adapter out of an MCU.  It would be a problem of moderate difficulty, perhaps not even a bad student assignment, though while tasks of this nature come up in the real world, this particular one seems a bit questionable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [project](https://easyeda.com/f.rossi/bme280-1-wire) to use a [DS28E17](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/ibutton-one-wire/ibutton/DS28E17.html) 1-wire to I2c bridge to interface to a BME280. I haven't tried it, but it seems like the best approach for 1-wire <=> BME280 that I've seen.  The other option would be to program something like a Microchip PIC or AVR to act as a 1-wire device, develop your own protocol on top of the 1-wire protocol, make up your own "family" for the device(s), etc.

Comment: The problem is the asker doesn't need generic one-wire, they need a one-wire device that answers in the exact way expected by their gizmo's fixed firmware.  That makes a custom MCU solution implementing exactly what the fixed-function host needs pretty much the _only_ choice, as previously explained.